# How can I create a single-line border in CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a CSS border. The output I am trying to produce would look like this:

```
-------------- MFG -----------------
```

I would like a solid line instead of dashed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML :

```
<h1><span>MFG</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
 h1 {border-top: 1px solid black; margin: 40px 0 0 0; }

 h1 span { position: relative; top: -25px; padding: 0 20px; background: white;}
```

**EDIT**

The container which will have --------MTG------- in it must have the following :

```
 text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 1):

**html**

`<hr/>`

**css**

```
hr{
    margin-top:30px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
hr:after {
    content: "MFG";
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; 
    top: -0.7em;  
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sivatumma/Gy2Ef/)

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the `<hr>` tag.

There's an example here of what you're trying to do:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/